# g++ undefined reference to ZMQ

Tags: c++, g++, zeromq

I developed my project on my workplace pc (where all is going well), but when I try to compile on my home pc (both ubuntu 12.04) I get the following message:

```
undefined reference to `zmq_sendmsg'
```

I can't understand what am I missing, since I see this

```
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3.0.0
```

so my ZeroMQ installation seems to be ok.
Can someone suggest what could I check?

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: You need to post how you call the compiler / linker. And you probably also need to post a  minimal example of your code. (That said, the author of ZeroMQ has [written a nice blog post](http://www.250bpm.com/blog:4) some time ago that demonstrates that he doesn’t really understand C++ so there’s always a chance that the error is in the library.)

Comment: Nice one :)  And he has departed for new project with a C-only interface.

Comment: eheh I don't think the error is in the library since on my workplace pc it runs correctly ;-). But also ZMQ examples run on my pc, just my code don't compile... :,(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you link you have to add -lzmq so the linker will pull in functions from libzmq.

Here's how I compile a hello world program:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lzmq
```

Answer (score 1):

We need the linker command you use to be able to tell.

Can you build some of the ZeroMQ example programs?  Can you build things with the v2 versions in Ubuntu, eg

```
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=40 dpkg -l|grep libzmq
ii  libzmq-dev     2.1.11-1ubuntu ZeroMQ lightweight messaging kernel (develop
ii  libzmq1        2.1.11-1ubuntu ZeroMQ lightweight messaging kernel (shared 
edd@max:~$
```

ZeroMQ is a pretty standard library as far as build tools go, so you must be missing something simple we should find.

Comment: Well yes, ZMQ examples compile and run too without problems. I'm editing with Eclipse, and in terminal I'm simply doing "qmake" (I'm using QT too) and it works, then I do "make" and get the error.

Comment: So you now have a proof of concept that your installation is complete.  And it would appear that 'build recipe' you brought home is not appropriate for your path settings.  You need to disentangle this -- `qmake` will be writing a Makefile for you which you need to debug. It may be as simple as correcting your `.pro` file.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but in ".pro" file the only row about ZMQ is

    LIBS += -lzmq

and zmq.hpp in the HEADERS section. I don't see any "wrong path" written anywhere... I don't know what to look for anymore...

Comment: You have "large" example that does not work, and a "small" example that does.  You now need to bring them closer together, starting from "small" and adding til you find what broke it.

Comment: If this could help you to get some good idea, if I try building from inside QTCreator I get the same error (always, only on home pc...)